# Program 'python' failed to run:

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python setup, but when i run the command "setup.py sdist", it does't work.

I already tried using cmd, and the PowerShell shows [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To46f.png)

```py
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="paquete",
    version="0.1",
    description="Paquete de redondeo y potencia",
    author="Sebastian Hernandez",
    author_email="",
    url="",
    packages=['calculos','calculos.redondeo_potencia']

)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the screenshot in the post directly using the editor instead of inserting a linked to it.

Comment: Do not include pictures of text. You can copy the output directly into your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have python in the environment variables? Do you have the latest setuptools and wheel packages (PATH)? The following is to upgrade the packages
    python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade setuptools wheel
Source: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/